# SimpleXML-Load Child-trying to get property

Tags: php, simplexml

I've got the following problem and I can't find my mistake probably?

I try load the following XML(Over 15k Lines) Structure:

```
<Config>
  <SystemFiles>
  <Core>
    <Info>
    <Network>
    <Capture>
    <Store>
      <Mount01>
      <Mount02>
    </Store>
  </Core>
</Config>
```

I need access to the Substructure of Store with each Child of it. My function looks like:

```
  public static function get_storage_data()
  {
    if(file_exists('/var/www/content/data/data.xml')) :
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('/var/www/content/data/data.xml');
        foreach ($xml->Config->Core->Store->children() as $mount) {
          echo $mount;
        }
    else:
        write_log(sprintf("data.xml not found"));
    endif;
  }
```

Which generates the following errors (Line 8 is the foreach line):

```
Notice
: Trying to get property 'Store' of non-object in
/var/www/inc/storage.inc
on line
8

Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function children() on null in /var/www/inc/storage.inc:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/storage.php(30): Storage::get_storage_data() #1 {main} thrown in
/var/www/inc/storage.inc
on line
8
```

What did I forget here or what is my mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the root node name when using SimpleXML to parse XML - it's already anchored at that level.

You should just be able to change the path from

```
$xml->Config->Core->Store->children()
```

to

```
$xml->Core->Store->children()
```

Note: I'm assuming that your `<Mount01>` and `<Mount02>` nodes just contain text content, since you won't be able to echo them otherwise.

See here for a worked example: https://eval.in/1006543

Comment: to be honest, there is no Text in ```<Mount01>``` its more another Node. Below that are informations in that construct. So i need the Value+Name```<Name>Value</name>```. Iam not sure how to solve that in a quite easy way.

Comment: @TheBadBossy `$element->asXML()`? `'Name=' . $element->getName() . ', Value=' . (string)element`?